# Data type problem

Tags: led

I have a program I would like to ask:
  I use the Bluetooth control LED to light up.
In the picture, the serial port window shows r, but the LED does not light up. What went wrong? Ask everyone, thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: you read val from Serial but not send it from Serial. do `val = BTSerial.read(); Serial.write(val);`

Answer (score -1):

it work ！非常謝謝。it work ！非常謝謝。it work ！非常謝謝。it work ！非常謝謝。it work ！非常謝謝。
[image]

Comment: Please answer in English. This is an English speaking site.

Comment: @Majenko as of what I understood he just changed his code according to what the user has commented under the question post